# Why do we use `length-i-1` in the inner loop of bubble sort algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bubble-sort

Using javascript, It's programmed to sort the elements in an array by asc order. I tried my best to understand why the inner loop uses `length-i-1`, but couldn't. Can anyone please help me understand why do we use it?

```
function bubbleSort(arr) {

    for(let i=0; i<= arr.length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j< arr.length-i-1; j++) {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                let lesser = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = lesser;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Everything at an index greater than `length-i-1` is already sorted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Daniel said in his comment, it is because those items have already been sorted (eg. the largest element that ends up at the highest index in the first iteration)

Watch the gif below, notice how the 8 ends up on the far right, and then gets surrounded by the black box, signifying that it will not need to be moved anymore, and therefor doesn't need to be checked anymore (it is greater than length-i-1).

[image: Bubble Sort in action]

Not checking these already 'locked in' elements helps to increase the algorithm speed.

Gif is from: [Bubble Sort on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: Easier with the gif than with words :D

Comment: Sometimes I think that is the easiest way to learn these kind of things!

Comment: True, but there are also times that you should sweat every word in order to understand something!

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about it in terms of steps:
Say you have an array of 10 elements just for the sake of an example.

**1st step**

```
i = 0, j goes from 0 to 9( = 10 - 0 - 1)
```

So it traverses the whole array.
Now, each time that we have that the current element is bigger than the next one we switch them (by `if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])`), so at the end of the first iteration, on the last position we will have the max element of the array.

**2nd step**

```
i = 1, j goes from 0 to 8( = 10 - 1 - 1)
```

Now, we can notice that we leave out the last (9th) position, but we know that it was already the maximum from the previous step, so it was in the correct position. At the end of this iteration we will have the 2nd maximum element on the 8th position, and the process continues..

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Too slow on the Phone :P

After every outer Iteration, the i-th greatest Element is at the correct place. So after the First Iteration, the greatest Element is on the far right Side. Now that we know that, we don't have to compare this element in the next round.
After the second Iteration, the second largest element is on the far right Side -1 Position. So the two largest Elements are already sorted and we don't have to consider them in the next round.

Try your algorithm with an easy example and step through it by hand. Then you should see it clearly.